# Household Appliances Scheduling Project using Genetic Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I'm an electrical engineering student, who is working on a residential load scheduling problem for my Final Year Project. I have little knowledge of genetic algorithm and Java programming and it's beyond what I've learned.  I would really appreciate if anyone could help me & my apologies for any ignorant questions I've asked.

---

### Residential Load Scheduling

I have been reading books and research papers to understand GA. My objective of my FYP is to schedule household appliances to turn on only during periods where electricity tariffs are lowest (given that the prices change every half-hourly).

I have decided to use genetic algorithm as the artificial intelligence technique to solve the problem, because it can effectively solve problems with large numbers of variables.

Assuming that a residential block consist of 100 household units and each unit owns 3 controllable loads (loads that can be shifted to other operation times without affecting the comfort of users) - washing machine, clothes dryer and dishwasher. Basically, the objective function is to minimize the multiplication of the summation of (appliance power consumption, electricity price and on/off state of it) along a time slot. The goal is to find the optimal solution (lowest cost) for these appliances along 48 time slots (time slot = 1/2 hour). As each appliance has a typical turn on period (e.g. washing machine 9-11pm, dryer 11pm-1am, & dish washer 7-10pm). The electricity price changes every half-hourly and remains constant within the time slot and the lowest tariff usually falls between 12am and 8 am.

I'm trying to instantiate the chromosome to contain a m x n matrix where m is the number of appliances (in this case, 3) and n is the number of time slots (48).

Example:

Where 0 and 1 represent off and on respectively
Chromosome 1:
      Washing Machine        Clothes Dryer              Dishwasher
[ [ 0 0 0 ... 1 1 0 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0 ... 1 1 0 ] [ 0 0 0 ... 1 1 1 1 0 ... 00 ] ]
in the format of 3 x 48 matrix

---

```
                                **UPDATES**
```

I have some questions regarding the coding part, that I would appreciate if you guys can help me.

Question 1: I am trying to generate an array of 48 binary 0s and 1s and fit in it to evaluate the fitness. Can someone help me to identify he error?

```
package HEMS;

public class Individual {

/**
 * In this case, the chromosome is an array of integers rather than a string. 
 */
private int[] chromosome;
private double fitness = -1;
public static final int CHROMOSOME_LENGTH = 48;

/**
 * Initializes individual with specific chromosome
 * 
 * The chromosome to give individual
 */
public Individual(int[] chromosome) {
    // Create individual chromosome
    this.chromosome = chromosome;
}

/**
 * Initializes random individual
 * 
 * The length of the individuals chromosome
 */
public Individual(int chromosomeLength) {
    // Create random individual
    this.chromosome = new int[chromosomeLength];

    /**
     * This constructor assumes that the chromosome is made entirely of 0s and
     * 1s, which may not always be the case, so make sure to modify as
     * necessary. This constructor also assumes that a "random" chromosome means
     * simply picking random zeroes and ones, which also may not be the case
     *
     */
    for (int gene = 0; gene < chromosomeLength; gene++) {

        if (0.5 < Math.random()) {

            this.setGene(gene, 1);

        } else {

            this.setGene(gene, 0);

        }
    }
}

/**
 * Gets individual's chromosome
 * 
 * @return The individual's chromosome
 */
public int[] getChromosome() {
    return this.chromosome;
}

/**
 * Gets individual's chromosome length
 * 
 * @return The individual's chromosome length
 */
public int getChromosomeLength() {
    return this.chromosome.length;
}

/**
 * Set gene at offset
 * 
 */
public void setGene(int offset, int gene) {
    this.chromosome[offset] = gene;
}

/**
 * Get gene at offset
 * 
 * @return gene
 */
public int getGene(int offset) {
    return this.chromosome[offset];
}

/**
 * Store individual's fitness
 * 
 * The individuals fitness
 */
public void setFitness(double fitness) {
    this.fitness = fitness;
}

/**
 * Gets individual's fitness
 * 
 * @return The individual's fitness
 */
public double getFitness() {
    return this.fitness;
}

public String toString() {
    String output = "";
    for (int gene = 0; gene < this.chromosome.length; gene++) {
        output += this.chromosome[gene] + ",";
    }
    return output;
}

}
```

Comment: For the two dimensionalty you can either use a `int[][]` which should work just fine. Or you can just use a `int[]` and calculate the index based on `row * lengthOfRow + column`. The latter is the more efficient approach generally speaking.

Comment: Thanks Mr @Ben for your advice. As I am still trying to understand how to code arrays in Java, may I know, for example this.genes = new int[Constants.CHROMOSOME_LENGTH]; , how do I edit the code to make it work in 2 dimensions?